# How can I ask this in a polite way?

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you please let me know how can I reject payment related offer from my client. Here is the scenario

My client is coming from the UK to meet me and other business related activities. He told me that he will pay for hotel and other local travelling bills. But I don't like it as I want to pay for his accommodation as we treat him as a guest.

How can I explain it in a polite way?

Comment: "We can take care of that for you."?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is:

> Dear... ,
>
> We appreciate your willingness to pay the hotel bills. It shows your
>   great consideration and tact. But I would like to assure you that we
>   are happy to treat you like a dear, very welcome guest. So, please let us cover the
>   expenses. We will be very pleased to do it.
>
> Best regards,
>
> ...

Use "we" if you mean not only yourself but your colleagues (company) as well. If there is only 1 person who will pay, and it's you, then you are free to use "I" (especially if your communication isn't too formal).